# Need help in configuring a simple TLS/SSL within k8s cluster for pod to pod communication over https

Tags: kubernetes, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, docker-desktop

Need help on how to configure TLS/SSL on k8s cluster for internal pod to pod communication over https. Able to curl http://servicename:port over http but for https i am ending up with NSS error on client pod.

I generated a self signed cert with CN=*.svc.cluster.local (As all the services in k8s end with this) and i am stuck on how to configure it on k8s.

Note: i exposed the main svc on 8443 port and i am doing this in my local docker desktop setup on windows machine.

1. No Ingress --> Because communication happens within the cluster itself.
2. Without any CRD(custom resource definition) cert-manager

Answer (score 3):

You can store your self-signed certificate inside the secret of Kubernetes and mount it to the volume of the pod.

If you don't want to use the CRD or cert-manager you can use the native Kubernetes API to generate the Certificate which will be trusted by all the pods by default.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

managing the self singed certificate across all pods and service might be hard I would suggest using the service mesh. Service mesh encrypts the network traffic using the `mTLS`.

[https://linkerd.io/2.10/features/automatic-mtls/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Linkerd%20automatically%20enables,TLS%20connections%20between%20Linkerd%20proxies](https://linkerd.io/2.10/features/automatic-mtls/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Linkerd%20automatically%20enables,TLS%20connections%20between%20Linkerd%20proxies).

Mutual **TLS** between service to service communication managed by the Side car containers in case of service mesh.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/

in this case, No ingress required and no **cert-manager** required.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Harsh. is my approach of generating a self signed certificate for CN=*.svc.cluster.local is correct, to enable https communication between the pods. if i create a secret of type tls and mount it there, will i be able to make https like below        https://<svcname>:port/health, where svcname is a service of type clusterIP.

Comment: i created a selfsigncert with the CN=*.svc.cluster.local, this has wild card character *. I used CN this way because, every svc in k8s end with svc.cluster.local.  i wrote a script which spins up two pods ( main and client) client pod invokes few main pod apis and exits. once the job is done, it kill the pods. There is no scope for external communication.  Please let me know the best approach for this usecase. communication over http is happening, wherea on https its closing the connection. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get 100% based on what I got from comment you can run the job or cronjob on k8s for client job as it is running and invoking the service. also you are right incase with using secret and mounting the cert inside the path of pod.